# String Comparison Error when Searching Blank Fields

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Searching through a column in a spreadsheet I notice that the second line will exception ("Nullable object must have a value.") when it comes across a blank field, however the first line will succeed. I have to add the `Bool` cast to the second line because otherwise I get "Cannot convert Nullable<bool> to bool". I assume this is the issue, but is there a way around that to allow blank fields to be checked?

```
keyFoundCell = _ws.Cells["a:a"].FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.Value?.ToString() == field.Key);
keyFoundCell = _ws.Cells["a:a"].FirstOrDefault(cell => (bool)cell.Value?.ToString().Equals(field.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Are you using Interop? Use `.Text` instead of `.Value`. Or do you mean this: `(bool)(cell.Value?.ToString().Equals(field.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));`

Comment: @ScottHannen Ah .Text seems to work. I'm using Epplus library which is similar to Interop. Want to drop that in as an answer?

Comment: @RufusL cell doesn't seem to have a `GetValueOrDefault` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both EPPlus and Excel Interop you can read a cell's contents using the `Text` property instead of the `Value` property if you want to operate on the cell's visible contents and avoid nulls. `Value` returns an `object` which might be null, but `Text` returns the visible text as a `string` which can be empty but won't be null.

If we're using `Value.ToString()` or `Value?.ToString()` then chances are we'd be better off with `Text` because that's a giveaway that we want the text we see, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the `?.` operator will return `null` right away if the left hand side of the operator is `null`.

So, when `cell.Value` is `null`, the first line works because you're doing a direct comparison using the `==` operator, which will return a `bool`. In other words, `null == field.Key` returns `false` (unless `field.Key` is `null`, of course).

The second line does not work without a cast because if the value is `null`, then the `?.` operator returns `null` and the rest of the line is ignored (`.ToString()` is never called). So the exception you're getting is due to the fact that the `if` condition must return a `bool`, yet it's returning a `Nullable<bool>` instead.

One way to fix this is to simply check for `null` first. This will not compare any objects where `cell.Value == null`:

```
keyFoundCell = _ws.Cells["a:a"].FirstOrDefault(cell => 
    cell.Value != null && 
    cell.Value.ToString().Equals(field.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Another way you can do this is to use the static `Equals` method of the `string` class, which will allow one or more `null` arguments. This will include results where `cell.Value == null` (and will return true for those cases where `field.Key` is also `null`):

```
keyFoundCell = _ws.Cells["a:a"].FirstOrDefault(cell => 
    string.Equals(cell.Value?.ToString(), field.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
keyFoundCell = _ws.Cells["a:a"].FirstOrDefault(cell => (bool?)cell.Value?.ToString().Equals(field.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ?? false;
```